# What I am missing in this simple equation from Nesterov's paper?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

In this paper by Prof Nesterov, [First-order methods of smooth convex optimization
with inexact oracle](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/12/2865.pdf), proof of Theorem 2, there is the following very simple equation which I think it is wrong,
\begin{align}
\Vert x_{k+1}-x^*\Vert^2 = \Vert x_{k}-x^*\Vert^2 + 2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_{k+1}-x^*\rangle -\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2
\end{align} 
(They defined norm as $\Vert x\Vert^2 =\langle Bx,x\rangle$)
Obviously, it must be 
\begin{align}
\Vert x_{k+1}-x^*\Vert^2 = \Vert x_k-x^*+x_{k+1}-x_{k}\Vert^2 = \Vert x_{k}-x^*\Vert^2 + 2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_{k}-x^*\rangle \\
+\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2
\end{align}
Am I missing something?

I also, checked journal version, [Mathematical Programming](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-013-0677-5).

Comment: You are not expanding it the way they have done. Use the fact that B is self adjoint linear operator. Notice the signs in the original statement, that should give you some hints. Alternatively, replace all the squared norms with inner product and simplify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The author is correct. The norm in question is induced by the real inner product $(x,y):=\langle Bx,y\rangle$ where $B$ is positive definite with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Let $u = x_{k+1} - x^\ast$ and $v = x_{k+1}-x_k$. Then the equation is simply saying that
$$
\|u\|^2 = \|u-v\|^2 + 2(v,u) - \|v\|^2,
$$
which is just a rearrangement of terms in the cosine law
$$
\|u-v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2(v,u) + \|v\|^2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

If it is bilinear, the derivation is correct.

$$2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_k-x^*\rangle +\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2=$$

$$=2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_k-x^*\rangle +2\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert ^2-\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2=$$

$$=2\left(\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_k-x^*\rangle +\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_{k+1}-x_k\rangle\right)-\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2=$$

$$=2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_k-x^*+x_{k+1}-x_k\rangle -\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2=$$

$$=2\langle B(x_{k+1}-x_k),x_{k+1}-x^*\rangle -\Vert x_{k+1}-x_k\Vert^2$$